# Error when opening eclipse with Spring Tools Suite

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite

I am using the Spring Tool Suite for eclipse. When I launch the program. I get the following message:

> An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Spring Tooling".
>
> Attempted to beginRule: P/some.package.name, does not match outer
>   scope rule: Beans Model Initialization

But I don't understand what it means

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you have initializated the beans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with the eclipse project. As this was a maven project, I was able to do the following:

I deleted the project in eclipse *(right click - delete)*. I then deleted the `.project` file from the directory and imported the project as *existing maven project*.

**(I think you can only do this if you are using maven)**

Answer (score 4):

It will work if you clean your project.
Eclipse-project-clean.

It works for me.